# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect -- office network

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am getting the following error while trying to connect to MongodDB Atlas while on the office network.
​
[image]

However, back on the home network, i am able to connect to the database.
Any guidance on how i could resolve this error while on the office network would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your [whitelist](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/).

Comment: my whitelist is set to ensure all IP addresses can access the database.